# Is It Legal to Cast Away the Sign on a Pointer?

Tags: c++, c-strings, strcpy, reinterpret-cast, unsigned-char

I am working in an antiquated code base that used `unsigned char*`s to contain strings. For my functionality I've used `string`s however there is a rub:

I can't use anything in `#include <cstring>` in the old code. Copying from a `string` to an `unsigned char*` is a laborious process of:

```
unsigned char foo[12];
string bar{"Lorem Ipsum"};

transform(bar.cbegin(), bar.cbegin() + min(sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]), bar.size()), foo, [](auto i){return static_cast<unsigned char>(i);});
foo[sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]) - 1] = '\0';
```

Am I going to get into undefined behavior or aliasing problems if I just do:

```
strncpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(foo), bar.c_str(), sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]) - 1);
foo[sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0]) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Do you need to be cross-platform here? Are you willing to settle for something that works on your current platform, even if it may strictly be UB in the C++ Standard? `char` is guaranteed to have the same representation as one of `signed char` or `unsigned char`, and even in the `signed` case, you are probably safe with strictly ACSII data: `[0,127]`.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios It is ASCII.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `static_cast<char *> or just a c style cast?

Comment: @BoBTFish I'm unwilling to use behavior that is undefined according to the standard. That's the reason I'm asking the question. Obviously I can use the `transform` it's just not clear what I'm doing.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala No. It should be a `reinterpret_cast`. If you try a `static_cast` the compiler will, rightly, give you the error: "`static_cast`: cannot convert from `unsigned char [12]` to `char *`"

Comment: @BeyelerStudios [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) already checks that for me.

Comment: A note on wording: you **cannot** store strings in `char*`s of any flavor. You store strings in `char` **arrays**, and you access the contents of those arrays through pointers, i.e., `char*`s. Muddling "array" and "pointer" leads to no end of confusion.

Comment: @PeteBecker, this is too much of the hair splitting for my taste. It is also not correct - I can certainly store strings in `char*` which never was an array

Comment: @SergeyA No, you can make a `char*` point to a string literal, which is of type `const char[nchars + 1]`.

Comment: @TartanLlama, but I can also point it to something else ;)

Comment: @SergeyA Sure, but you'll be pointing it to some other array of characters or a single character.

Comment: @TartanLlama, but why? `int x[255]; char* s = x; s[0] = 'A';` is perfectly legal. Also, `struct Blob { double x, y, z; } blob; char* s = &blob; s[3] = 'C' ` is legal as well.

Comment: @SergeyA The comment you disagreed with was talking about strings. Your first example is modifying the value representation of an `int`, your second example is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @TartanLlama, not sure if I follow. In the first example I tried to show how I can store strings in something which was never a char array (but it was an int array). In the next I've shown how to store strings into something which never was an array. Why do you think it is an undefined behaviour?

Comment: @TartanLlama, can't go to the chat from my office computer :)

Comment: @SergeyA Maybe we can work this out then clear up our comments. I guess some of this comes down to what you define as "string", but I'd say your first example is doing operations on the object representation rather than doing anything with strings. I think your second example is undefined behaviour as pointer arithmetic is only defined within an array.

Comment: @TartanLlama, interesting indeed, but I am too little of the language lawer to answer this. I think, I will ask a question.

Comment: Anyone looking for the new @SergeyA question can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34879858/2642059

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an explicit exception to the strict aliasing rule for `[unsigned] char`, so casting pointers between character types will just work.

Specifically in [N3690](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) [basic.types] says that any trivially copyable object can be copied into an array of `char` or `unsigned char`, and if then copied back the value is identical.  It also says if you copy the same array into a second object, the two objects are identical. (Paragraphs two and three)

[basic.lval] says it is legal to change an object through an lvalue of `char` or `unsigned char` type.

The concern expressed by BobTFish in the comments about whether values in `char` and `unsigned char` is misplaced I think.  "Character" values are inherently of `char` type.  You can store them in `unsigned char` and use them as `char` later - but that was happening already.

(I'd recommend writing a few in-line wrapper functions to make the whole thing less noisy, but I assume the code snippets were for exposition rather than actual usage.)

**Edit**: Remove erroneous recommendation to use `static_cast`.

**Edit2**: Chapter and verse.

Comment: You cannot do `static_cast<char*>` as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878710/is-it-legal-to-cast-away-the-sign-on-a-pointer#comment57495575_34878710

Comment: Call me a skeptic, but I'd sure like to see a source on this especially after the whole `static_cast` debacle.

Comment: Yup.  Saw your comment above and changed my answer (before your comment here appeared!)

Comment: Funny.  I was just thinking "rather casts my assertion on strict aliasing into doubt".

Comment: That's for accessing the object representation, isn't it? I.e. you can cast a pointer to any object to `(unsigned) char*` and back, and copy it if the object is *trivially copyable*. But I don't see any guarantees about the actual character values being the same. (Unless `char` is `unsigned`, which is *implementation defined*).

Comment: You cite that this is legal for trivially copyable types. But is an array trivially copyable? I thought that was specifically not the case.

Comment: Even if the array is not trivially copyable, each of the elemental chars or unsigned chars is.

Comment: You seem to be saying that this error from GCC is a bug: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘char*’ to type ‘uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}’ but that's the error I'm getting. I have to reinterpret_cast to suppress it. Making the type explicit doesn't help: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘char*’ to type ‘unsigned char*’. This does work for the underlying char vs unsigned char cast, but not for the pointers. IME, anyway.

Comment: @CodeAbominator : No, the warning is correct.  You need to use reinterpret cast.  What I am saying is that once you have done the reinterpret cast, using the pointer is not undefined behaviour (it doesn't violate the strict aliasing rules).