# Pointer arithmetics on non-array types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-punning, char-pointer

Let's consider following piece of code:

```
struct Blob {
    double x, y, z;
} blob;

char* s = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&blob);
s[2] = 'A';
```

Assuming that sizeof(double) is 8, does this code trigger undefined behaviour?

Comment: This wouldn't even compile without a cast though.

Comment: Is this C? In C++ this will not compile.

Comment: This is not legal C or C++, you need a cast. Once you have a cast, this is legal and well-defined. Of course anything can happen if you try to access blob.x afterwards.

Comment: @Bathsheba, added the cast, question remains.

Comment: @n.m. hint - the question is regarding pointer arithmetics on non-arrays.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is done on pointers. All pointers involved must point into the same array. Any POD/trivial-layout/whatever-its-name object can be treated as an array of `char` or its differently signed siblings. This is the basis of functions like `memcpy` or `fread`.

Comment: @hvd You do realize that the quote refers to the fact that both pointers point to the same array (or to the hypothetical element past it)? Your interpretation is incorrect.

Comment: @n.m., this is common sense answer, not a language-lawyer one :)

Comment: In this particular case I bet on **no undefined behavior here**. You struct has only `double`s in it so no padding is necessary. In case if padding __is__ required you could get a __unspecified__ behavior (I guess). Still a language-lawyer opinion required.

Comment: I don't see any pointer arithmetic happening here. I see array accessing, but that's not pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @NicolBolas s[2] = *(s+2)

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from N4140 (roughly C++14):

> **3.9 Types [basic.types]**
>
> 2 For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type `T`, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type `T`, the underlying bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into an array of `char` or `unsigned char`.<sup>42</sup> If the content of the array of `char` or `unsigned char` is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value.
>
> 42) By using, for example, the library functions (17.6.1.2) `std::memcpy` or `std::memmove`.
>
> 3 For any trivially copyable type `T`, if two pointers to `T` point to distinct `T` objects `obj1` and `obj2`, where neither `obj1` nor `obj2` is a base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes (1.7) making up `obj1` are copied
>   into `obj2`,<sup>43</sup> `obj2` shall subsequently hold the same value as `obj1`. [ *Example:* ... ]
>
> 43) By using, for example, the library functions (17.6.1.2) `std::memcpy` or `std::memmove`.

This does, in principle, allow assignment directly to `s[2]` if you take the position that assignment to `s[2]` is indirectly required to be equivalent to copying all of some other `Blob` into an array that just happens to be bytewise identical except for the third byte, and copying it into your `Blob`: you're not assigning to `s[0]`, `s[1]`, etc. For trivially copyable types including `char`, that is equivalent to setting them to the exact value they already have, which also has no observable effect.

However, if the only way to get `s[2] == 'A'` is by memory manipulation, then a valid argument could also be made that what you're copying back into your `Blob` *isn't* the underlying bytes that made up any previous `Blob`. In that case, technically, the behaviour would be undefined by omission.

I do strongly suspect, especially given the "whether or not the object holds a valid value of type `T`" comment, that it's intended to be allowed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101136/discussion-on-answer-by-hvd-pointer-arithmetics-on-non-array-types).

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 3.10 of the standard seems to allow for that specific case, assuming that "access the stored value" means "read or write", which is unclear.

> 3.10-10
>
> If a program attempts to **access the stored value of an object through
> a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
> undeﬁned**:
>
> —(10.1) the dynamic type of the object,
>
> —(10.2) a cv-qualiﬁed version of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> —(10.3) a type similar (as deﬁned in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the
> object,
>
> —(10.4) a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to
> the dynamic type of the object,
>
> —(10.5) a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a
> cv-qualiﬁed version of the dynamic type of the object,
>
> —(10.6) an aggregate or union type that includes one of the
> aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic data members
> (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a
> subaggregate or contained union),
>
> —(10.7) a type that is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) base class type of the
> dynamic type of the object,
>
> —(10.8) **a char or unsigned char type**.